# Error booting Windows 7 system: "<random name> is compressed / Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart"

Tags: windows-7, boot

```
DZNRX is compressed
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

This computer has Windows 7 on it. The user called me to help him. I only know that this PC has Windows 7.

I have not found any reference about this message on Google. I have never seen something like that.

Do you have any idea what this error means?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Windows 7 Boot Error: "some file" is compressed. Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart

> After switching on your computer or after restarting Windows 7 you
>   receive the error ‘filename’ is compressed. Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to
>   restart on a black screen with white writing when trying to boot into
>   Windows.
>
> The ‘filename’ is different on different systems but the following
>   have been reported:
>
> ```
> BootMgr is compressed.  Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart.
> QXHDK is compressed.  Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart.
> NTLDR is compressed.  Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart.
> DFJEU is compressed.  Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart.
> VUFEI is compressed.  Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart.
> DGKAR is compressed.  Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart.
> ```
>
> #### Explanation
>
> A bug in Windows 7 file compression is causing this problem.  We can
>   solve the problem by decompressing the hard disk as shown below.
>
> #### Decompress using Windows System Recovery menu
>
> 1. Boot to the Windows System Recovery Options screen.  If you don’t know how to do that the see this article: Windows 7 or Vista System
>      Recovery Options
> 2. On the System Recovery Options screen click LOAD DRIVERS button.
>
>    [image]
> 3. On the left, click Computer.  You should now see your Local Disk C: on the right.
> 4. Right click Local Disk C: and click Properties.
> 5. At the bottom of the properties box, deselect the box that says Compress this drive to save space.
> 6. Another window will pop up asking you to confirm the attribute change. (the windows might get a bit messy so you’ll just have to move
>      them around the screen so you can see them properly)
> 7. Select Apply changes to drive C:, subfolder and files and click OK
> 8. Now I would suggest waiting.  You will not see a progress dialog as it uncompresses the drive so give it a few minutes until your hard
>      disk stops showing activity.
> 9. When finished, cancel all remaining dialog boxes and restart the computer.

Source [Windows 7 Boot Error: ‘some file’ is compressed. Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart](http://www.proposedsolution.com/solutions/windows-7-filename-is-compressed-press-ctrl-alt-del-to-restart/)

Comment: Another way I've found is by clicking 'Next', going on the console and type `start notepad.exe`. Then, on the meny, go on 'File > Open' and proceed from step 3. This may be useful if you need to load 3rd party drivers and can't use that option.

Comment: Good write up, saved me the time to figure it out, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The first stage of the Windows bootloader cannot read [compressed NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#File_compression) files. These files include BOOTMGR and [NTLDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLDR), which are used for the second stage of the [Windows boot process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_startup_process#Boot_loader_phase_2). If they are in fact compressed, an error message like the following would be returned:

```
[NTLDR|BOOTMGR] is compressed
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

Try booting from a Windows installation or recovery disk, then use the command prompt to decompress the files—running [`COMPACT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726045.aspx)`/U /I NTLDR BOOTMGR DZNRX` on the root directory of the system partition might fix the problem. If required, repeat the process for any other files the system complains about.